# Sphinx Documenter doesn't run

Tags: cygwin, python-sphinx

I have this installed on my linux box at home but decided to install it through cygwin here at work. The install went fine, the problem is that running the command:

```
$ sphinx-build -b html AisisGit/AisisCoreDoc/doc SphynxDocBuild/
```

Doesn't do anything. No errors, no output no files generated. Nothing.

This is the exact out put:

```
user.user@D0000004280 /cygdrive/c/users/adam.balan/Dropbox
$ sphinx-build -b html AisisGit/AisisCoreDoc/doc SphynxDocBuild/

user.user@D0000004280 /cygdrive/c/users/adam.balan/Dropbox
$
```

Running this command at home works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The workaround for me was to install all packages in the Devel category.